# JQuery unobtrusive still validates removed HTML DOM

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I have an ajax partial view that is created, and after it's created I use

`jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#recommend_fields');`

To turn on unobstrusive validation!

Great!

Now when I completely remove the `DOM` i.e.

`$('#recommend_fields').remove()`

And I click submit, it still tries to validate it. My `ModelState` shows errors with regards to the `Id's` that used to exist inside `recommend_fields`.

Any reason for this?

**AJAX REQUEST**

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "/SomeArea/SomeController/CreateView",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html"
});
request.done(function (msg, text) {
    if (text == "success") {
        $('#recommmended_sys').empty().append(msg);

        jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#recommend_fields');
    }
});
```

**N.B**

Please remember that the above are snippets, they do work, I just want to know how to turn off unobtrusive validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't use unobtrusive validation in the end because when the DOM is gone it won't validate client side anyway, it validates server side (noob school boy error).

So in the server side I just did this:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid && vm.SectionMarkedForDeletion)
    ModelState.ToList().ForEach(x =>
        {
            if (x.Key.Contains("Section"))
                x.Value.Errors.Clear();
        });
```

`x.Key.Contains("Section")` literally is checking for any field which `Id` contains `Section` which is the bit I add.

I then proceed to use some service providers to sort out the rest of the `Model` then save it :)